# DataTable IN syntax performance

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable with 10k records.

If I select 1k records from the datatable using **foreach**, everything seems OK.

But when I combine all 1k records in an **IN** sql query, the select command takes much more time to finish.

test code:

```
DataTable cacheTable = new DataTable() {Columns = {{"ID", typeof(int)}, {"TEXT", typeof(string)}}};
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    cacheTable.Rows.Add(i, "aaaaaaa");
}
List<object> ids = new List<object>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    ids.Add(cacheTable.Rows[i]["ID"]);
}
Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
w.Start();
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    cacheTable.Select(string.Format("ID='{0}'", id));
}
w.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("=:");
Console.WriteLine("ElapsedMilliseconds: {0}", w.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("ElapsedTicks: {0}", w.ElapsedTicks);
Console.WriteLine("ElapsedTicks: {0}", w.Elapsed);
string sql = string.Format("ID in ('{0}')", string.Join("','", ids));
Stopwatch w1 = new Stopwatch();
w1.Start();
var rows = cacheTable.Select(sql);
w1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("IN:");
Console.WriteLine("ElapsedMilliseconds: {0}", w1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("ElapsedTicks: {0}", w1.ElapsedTicks);
Console.WriteLine("ElapsedTicks: {0}", w1.Elapsed);
```

output:

```
=:
ElapsedMilliseconds: 20
ElapsedTicks: 47827
ElapsedTicks: 00:00:00.0204534
IN:
ElapsedMilliseconds: 557
ElapsedTicks: 1303385
ElapsedTicks: 00:00:00.5573985
```

why is it happened?

Also, is there any recommends while using the DataTable Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTable.Select` takes an SQL-like query, parses it and executes it. It's a very powerful and flexible feature, but it has no promise to perform as good as custom code.

My recommendation:

1. Avoid the `DataTable` class if you can. It is known to be very heavy and usually encourages bad design decisions.
2. If you are going to use it anyhow, avoid using the `Select` method for things you can easily code yourself.

Comment: my program needs to **select** and **update** sqlserver table very frequently. so I created a DataTable to cache the whole table. All **select** reads from the cache Datatable. All **update** update the cache table and async update the remote sqlserver table.  If i avoid the DataTable, could you please recommend something that can fit this situation?

Comment: There are endless options, you can use an `ORM` like `NHibernate` or `EntityFramework`. `DataTable` is bad for all kinds of reasons you can read about if you google it. But remember that making yourself do more work might not be the best idea. If it works for you performance-wise and the program isn't trying to use best practices with code that will be shared with a lot of developers, than maybe keeping the `DataTable` is the right thing for you. If you decide to get rid of it, I'd recommend checking out `EntityFramework`.